# Expect: 100-Continue - How to Write Module and Test Client

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to test the behavior of an "expect: 100-continue" request being handled in an IHttpModule.

What I want to do is create a request in a client with the header `expect: 100-continue` and send it to the server. The server will immediately return a 500. Theoretically, the payload (file) should never be sent if the server returns a 500 instead of a 100.

I'm not seeing the expected behavior. This is what I'm doing...

Here is the server code (http module):

```
using System;
using System.Web;

namespace WebSite
{
    public class Expect100ContinueModule : IHttpModule
    {
        private HttpApplication httpApplication;

        public void Init(HttpApplication context)
        {
            httpApplication = context;

            context.BeginRequest += ContextBeginRequest;
        }

        private void ContextBeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var request = httpApplication.Context.Request;
            var response = httpApplication.Context.Response;
            if(!request.Url.AbsolutePath.StartsWith("/Upload"))
            {
                return;
            }

            response.StatusCode = 500;
            response.End();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I'm running this in IIS 7 with the integrated pipeline.

Here is the client code:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

namespace ConsoleClient
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:83/Upload/");
            request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = true;
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";

            var buffer = File.ReadAllBytes("Test - Copy.txt");
            var text = File.ReadAllText("Test - Copy.txt");
            using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                requestStream.Flush();
            }
            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            var x = "";
        }
    }
}
```

From what I'm seeing, the request has the file content even when the 500 is returned.

One issue I ran into is, Fiddler automatically handles expect: 100-continue by buffering the request, returning 100, and continuing with the full request.

I then tried WireShark. To get that to work, I had to capture the traffic with `RawCap` and read the output with WireShark. From what I can tell, this still shows the full payload on the request.

Now I have a few questions.

1. Is the server code actually returning the 500 first, or has a 100 already been returned before I get the BegineRequest event?
2. Is there a better way to write the client? I don't understand why you would write your full payload to the request stream before the request is made. The server module doesn't get the BeginRequest event until the clients Request.GetResponse() method is called.
3. Is there a good way to test the actual traffic on localhost?

**[Update]**

I couldn't find a way to test locally so I used a neighbor employees desktop to test with also. I was able to test with WireShark this way.

From what I can tell, there is no way to have the HttpWebClient do a PUT request to IIS without having the full file sent, even if an IHttpModule returns an error immediately before the file is completely uploaded.

I don't know if the issue is in the client (HttpWebClient) or the server (IIS). I don't know if using raw sockets and implementing the HTTP protocol by hand would make a difference.

If anyone has any more insight into this, please let me know.

Comment: There might be a Fiddler preference (fiddler.network.streaming.leakhttp1xx) you can change:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fiddler/archive/2011/11/05/http-expect-continue-delays-transmitting-post-bodies-by-up-to-350-milliseconds.aspx

Comment: It seems that the request you are making will always have the Path of "Upload" and you have a condition saying that if it isn't upload, then return, otherwise return a 500. Could this be the issue, or am I reading it wrong?